# How often does the shop refresh its stock of materials?

Tags: dust-an-elysian-tail

It seems that the stock of each material increases by 1 after a certain period of time. So what exactly is this interval?

Comment: I believe it's every in-game half hour.

Comment: The amount restocked varies along the game (increases over chapters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shops restock **every 4 in-game minutes**, and the amount of materials restocked varies along the game (increases over chapters).

Source: http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/609388-dust-an-elysian-tail/69155649